# C++ template functions through Cython

Tags: c++, python-2.7, cython

I generated a simple C++ header file lerp1d.h with a templated function and it's definition

lerp1d.h:

```
template <typename T> std::vector<T> LinearInterp(std::vector<T> x_data, std::vector<T> x_target, std::vector<T> f_vals) {
...}
```

Then I wanted to compile this function with Cython and use it in a python program together with numpy, the basic idea is to test it together with plotting utilities etc.

So I went ahead and created the following files:

cy_lerp1d.pyx:

```
# distutils: language = c++
# distutils: sources = lerp1d.
import Cython
cimport numpy as np

cdef extern from "<vector>" namespace "std":
    cdef cppclass vector [T]:
        cppclass iterator:
            T operator*()
            iterator operator++()
            bint operator==(iterator)
            bint operator!=(iterator)
            vector()
            void push_back(T&)
            T& operator[](int)
            T& at(int)
            iterator begin()
            iterator end()

cdef extern from "lerp1d.h":
    cdef vector[double] LinearInterp(vector[double]&, vector[double]&, vector[double]&)
```

As I understand it the last statement creates a template instantiation for double, Next

setup.py:

```
from distutils.core import setup
from distutils.extension import Extension
from Cython.Distutils import build_ext
import numpy
import os

os.environ["CC"]  = "g++ -std=c++11 -Wall"
os.environ["CXX"] = "g++ -std=c++11 -Wall"

#To build call with $python setup build_ext -i
setup(name = 'cy_lerp1d', ext_modules = 
    [Extension("cy_lerp1d", sources=["cy_lerp1d.pyx"],
     language = "c++" , include_dirs = [numpy.get_include()],
     cmdclass = {'build_ext' : build_ext})
```

And finally the test code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from cy_lerp1d import * #LinearInterp

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Some code...
```

I build the Cython extension with: `python setup.py build_ext -i` and it gives no errors
However when I try to run the test I get

```
 NameError: name 'LinearInterp' is not defined
```

If in the import statement I do from cy_lerp1d import LinearInterp I get:

```
ImportError: cannot import name LinearInterp
```

I am afraid I cannot find anything relevant to this situation so far, any help is welcome.

Answer (score 0):

I apologize that was an error on the code in test. Other than that this seems a valid way to do it. Another thing to note is that in the .pyx module one has to def a python function that will act as a wrapper there is no way to call the cpp function directly, so in cy_lerp1d.pyx: I added:

```
def LinearInterpCPP(x_v, x_t, f):
    return LinearInterp(x_v, x_t, f)
```